# Multiply using Aggregates Class in Mongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

So, I'm using MongoDB on Java via Maven and the Aggregation Framework for the selects. I have this document on the collection orders:

```
{ 
      "_id" : "orderKey0", 
      "orderdate" : 3, 
      "shippriority" : 0, 
      "customer" : { 
          "nationKey" : "nationKey0", 
          "mktsegment" : "mktsegment0" 
       }, 
      "lineitems" : { 
          "suppkey" : "suppkey1", 
          "quantity" : 9, 
          "extendedPrice" : 45, 
          "discount" : 18, 
          "tax" : 0, 
          "returnflag" : "b", 
          "linestatus" : "c", 
          "shipdate" : 4, 
          "shipingdate" : 1 
       } 
   }
```

I need to do this select:

```
SELECT sum(quantity) as sum_qty,
sum(extendedprice) as sum_base_price, sum(l_extendedprice*(1-l_discount)) as
sum_disc_price
FROM *
WHERE shipdate <= '[date]'
GROUP BY returnflag, linestatus
```

I don't know how to multiply and substract using the Aggregates class, any idea? I'm really blocked :S
Note I have a more documents in the collections for the use of the group by.
This is what I have done with the Aggregation Framework.

```
MongoCollection<Document> ordersCollection = database.getCollection("orders");

ordersCollection.aggregate(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            Aggregates.unwind("$lineitems"),
                            Aggregates.match(Filters.lte("lineitems.shipdate", 10)),
                            Aggregates.group("$lineitems.linestatus",
                                    Accumulators.sum("sum_qty", "$lineitems.quantity"),
                                    Accumulators.sum("sum_base_price", "$lineitems.extendedPrice"))
                    )
            ).forEach(printBlock);
```

Comment: It looks like you can build a raw document to use an expression. as described in the "Use Aggregation Expressions" section [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/aggregation/). You can then use any of [these expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#expression-operators) to do addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc. It looks like you might also be able to use a `new Document` as the first argument to `group` to get it to group by both `lineitems.linestatus` and `lineitems.returnflag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expressions to create nested arithmetic calculations.

Something like below

```
 Document groupFields = new Document();
 groupFields.append("linestatus", "$lineitems.linestatus");
 groupFields.append("returnflag", "$lineitems.returnflag");

 Document subtractDisc = new Document("$subtract", Arrays.asList(1, "$lineitems.discount"));
 Document multiplyDisc = new Document("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$lineitems.extendedPrice", subtractDisc));

ordersCollection.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Aggregates.unwind("$lineitems"),
                        Aggregates.match(Filters.lte("lineitems.shipdate", 10)),
                        Aggregates.group(groupFields,
                                Accumulators.sum("sum_qty", "$lineitems.quantity"),
                                Accumulators.sum("sum_base_price", "$lineitems.extendedPrice"),
                                Accumulators.sum("sum_disc_price", multiplyDisc)
                          )
                        )
  ).forEach(printBlock);
```